# Вывести результат в нужном порядке перемноженных чисел в массиве js

Tags: javascript

Есть поле input в которое водиться число

```
<input type="text" id="keyup-input"/>
```

у меня есть числа в массиве я и их получил так

```
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.days_to'), function(element) {
    element.textContent = element.textContent; 
 });
```

А теперь нужно ведённое число перемножать на все числа `element.textContent` и вывести их в input

```
var inputCountQuantity = document.querySelectorAll('.count_quantity_product');
inputKeyUp.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    Array.from(inputCountQuantity).map(function(item) {
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.days_to'), function(element) {
        item.value = e.target.value * element.textContent;

            console.log(item.value)
        });
    });
});
```

я это сделал так и получил следующий результат

`23.75
0
1.5
0
0.5
0
3.75
0.5
4
0`

вывело мне все правильно но вставилось во все input

```
<input type="number" class="count_quantity_product" value = '0'>
```

последние число то есть 0

Можно ли сделать что бы вставились числа по порядку

`<input type="number" class="count_quantity_product" value='23.75'> итд`

Comment: Добавить переменную, и в неё конкатинацией всё это поместить. А затем вывести в инпут

Comment: ` count = e.target.value; days = element.textContent; result += count * days; item.value = result;` подскажите что делаю не так ?

Comment: Да, заведи промежуточную переменную, в которой будешь хранить умноженные числа, а вне цикла уже присвой её в инпут

Answer (score 0):

```js
const

f = document.forms.f,
x = f.x,
a = [...f ['a[]']],
b = [...f ['b[]']],
h = ev => b.forEach ((i, j) => f ['b[]'] [j].value = + a [j].value * + ev.target.value)

x.addEventListener ('keyup', h)
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <input name="a[]" value="0">
  <input name="a[]" value="1">
  <input name="a[]" value="2">
  <br/>
  <input name="b[]">
  <input name="b[]">
  <input name="b[]">
  <hr/>
  <input name="x">
</form>
```